# How to add a custom message to a pattern validation in ko validation

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

Let's say I have:

```
self.UserName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true }).extend({ pattern: '[\S]' });
```

I'm trying to do something like (I've tried a few variations):

```
self.UserName = ko.observable("").extend({ required: true }).extend({ pattern: '[\S]', message : 'cannot contain spaces' });
```

But no luck.

I can see [validation bindings](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Validation-Bindings) mentions validation messages, but it appears to be for a single message for all validation.

And [custom validation rules](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation/wiki/Custom-Validation-Rules) seems over kill, as all I want is a pattern but with a different message.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. You need to assign an object to the `pattern` property which contains the `message` and the `params`

So the correct usage is:

```
self.UserName = ko.observable("")
    .extend({ required: true })
    .extend({ pattern: {
         message: 'cannot contain spaces',
         params: '[\S]'
}});
```

Se also the [Getting Started](https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation) example.

Comment: Bugger, can't believe I missed that! Thanks,